# JS не работает в chrome

Tags: google-chrome, javascript, html

```
<style>
    html,
    body {
        margin: 0px;
        min-height: 100%;
        min-width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
    }
    ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
    li {
        display: none;
        padding: 5px;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("ul li:first").show();
        $('#username').keydown(function (event) {
            var username = $(this).val();
            if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                $(this).hide().next();
                $("li").next("li#password").slideDown({
                    duration: 'slow'
                });
            }
        });
        $('#password').keydown(function entsub(event, ourform) {
            if (event && event.which == 13) {
                ourform.submit();
            }
        });

    })
</script>
<div class="reset-shown" id="email-row">
    <form action="http://www.cs.tut.fi/cgi-bin/run/~jkorpela/echo.cgi" method="post">
        <ul>
            <li id="username">
                <label for="email">Username:</label>
                <input id="username1" name="name" type="text"/>
                <div id="com">Please enter your username</div>
            </li>
            <li id="password">
                <label for="email">Password:</label>
                <input id="password1" name="name" onkeypress="return entsub(event,this.form)" type="text"/>
                <div id="com">Please enter your password</div>
            </li>
            <li class="submit">
                <input id="submit" type="submit" value=" Register "/>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
</div>
```

В мозиле все работает, есть первое поле ввода, заполняешь его, нажимаешь Enter, появляется второе "password", заполняешь, нажимаешь Enter - данные отправляются! В chrome они никуда не отправляются(  В чем может быть дело?

Answer (score 3):

А зачем такие сложности?

Во первых, нужно учитывать что JavaScript в браузере может быть отключенным. Поэтому `display: none` в стилях - плохой вариант. Юзер без JavaScript залогиниться не сможет.

Во вторых, стоит знать что, по умолчанию, `enter` в `<input>`-полях формы автоматически сабмитит эту форму.

Поэтому, достаточно такого кода:

```
​j​Query(function($){
    $('#pass').hide();
    $('#user')
        .focus()
        .keydown(function( event ){
            if( event.keyCode==13 ){
                $('#pass').show('false').focus();
                return false;// не даст сделать автосабмит
            }
        });
})​;​
```

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/KiTE/6xcgQ/)

Comment: Да но, мне нужно чтоб в место login появлялся password. И всегда видно одно поле! И чтоб не было видно кнопки. 
Такие условия=(

Comment: Тогда так:

    jQuery(function($){
        $('#user').focus()
            .keydown(function( event ){
                if( event.keyCode==13 ){
                    $(this).hide();
                    $('#pass').show().focus();
                    return false;
                }
            });
        $('#pass').hide()
            .keydown(function( event ){
                if( event.keyCode==13 ){
                    $(this).submit();
                    return false;
                }
            });
    });​

Comment: Если юзер отключил JS, его проблемы. А таких очень мало.  Если он отключил, значит понимает что почем, и включит.

Comment: @forum3, бесспорно. Но не стоит забывать о правилах хорошего тона - кодить так, чтобы при любых обстоятельствах было доступно максимум функционала.

Comment: Ну в принципе правильно, я так и сделал, когда есть ява, будет работать как задумано, когда её нет будет обычная форма=)

Но есть еще проблема, я хотел чтоб кнопка всегда была скрыта!!!!
добавил 
$('#submit')
.hide();
В мозиле все работает а хром все равно отвергает на последнем этапе=(((